# Is there a way to create an Azure Speech Studio evaluation accuracy test using more than one data file?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

When creating an evaluation accuracy test in Azure Speech Studio is there a way of basing the test on more than one dataset? Alternatively, is there a way of combining small datasets into one larger file?

I've had problems uploading large datasets so need to be able to combine two or more smaller datasets when creating tests.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will be able to test only against **one dataset** at this point of time.

[image: notice]

Please refer to [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-test-and-train) for more information.